# Testing a stylesheet with resources on a different server

Tags: html, css

I have a stylesheet that has stuff inside like `background: url(/images/foo.gif)` that I copied from `live` to `test`.  It works fine on `live`, but not on `test`.  This is because `test` does not have the `/images` contents.  Other than doing a find/replace from "url(/" to "url(http://live/" or copying `/images` to `test`, is there a good way to fix this? Note that when test pages that are on `test` go live, they will be on `live`.

Comment: I'm getting the impression that the answer to my question is, "No, there is not a good way to fix this." Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to have a copy of your images folder on each server.

Answer (score 0):

Once the image folder is not relative to the location of the stylesheet, you will need to replace the /images of the test with the absolute location of http://live/images.

Answer (score 0):

So in summary, you need to change the CSS of `test` to point to the live images, but you need to do it without modifying the CSS?  I guess if it was easy, you wouldn't have asked.

One suggestion might be to create an alternate `test`-only stylesheet that overrides the relevant classes and points to the production images properly, but only gets loaded on `test`.  How you would accomplish this would depend on your code.  If you maintain separate `live` and `test` config files, you can probably work it in to the configuration (ie. if `test.css` exists, include it).

Answer (score 0):

You could use software such as [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to remap /images/ to http://live/images/ — all testers would need a copy installed.

You could also install a proxy, such as [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html), on the webserver.

Comment: Actually, this is somewhat akin to how the real setup is going to work, though the reasoning for doing it this way is to solve a different problem than the one I am asking about.

Answer (score -1):

You could put <base href="live"> in the <head> of test. This replaces the current domain with the given href in all urls that begin with /.

Comment: This doesn't pass through to stylesheets (except possibly in Netscape 4.x)

Comment: That's the strategy I used with the html itself.